# Arangodb Traversal: Will my traversal will be endless if set the visitor to counting

Tags: arangodb

I have a custom function for visitor that just print out something. Essentially it will not modify result at all.

But then will the traversal going on foreverif it meets a cycle graph? Since it will not know which path is already visited (default setting)

Comment: Post your code, or a minimal example showing the behaviour you're concerned about.